# One of my paragraphs isn't following the "text-align-last" center justify property

Tags: html, css, shopify, text-align

I'm working on a Shopify store currently and tweaking the code to make the multiple paragraphs of a `<div>` justified while the last line is aligned to the center.

However, the second paragraph in the `div` is following the first property, but not the one for the last line. So I have a single paragraph with the text aligning to the left.

Here's what my `css` code looks like:

```
.rte-setting.mega-subtitle p {
  text-align: justify; 
  text-align-last: center;
  /*width: 70%;*/
  position: relative;
}
```

It might just be a Shopify thing, but can anyone help?

Comment: We need an [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last paragraph in a block behave differently you want to use the last-of-type pseudo class.

```
.rte-setting.mega-subtitle p {
  text-align: justify; 
}
.rte-setting.mega-subtitle p:last-of-type {
  text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
text-align: justify !important;
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't seem to work. It seems that Shopify is being annoying. Thanks for your help though!